# PHP5.3 closures indentation in VIM

Tags: php, vim, closures

I have tried few different php indentation scripts, but they can't handle indentation of the following code:

```
myfunc(function(){
    echo "hello";
    if(1==2){
        echo "world";
    }
});
```

Can you point out vimrc settings or php indentation file for vim which would handle new syntax of PHP5.3?

**Update:** Here is what I get:

```
myfunc(function(){
        echo "hello";
        if(1==2){
        echo "world";
        }
        });
```

I use bundled indent for 7.3 from http://www.2072productions.com/vim/indent/php.vim John Wellesz

Remaining PHP syntax is indented correctly.

Comment: If he is coding via SSH(Assumption), GUI editors is an not option, or unless Gedit has SSH.

Comment: Please could you edit your question so that we can see what you see? Here it seems to be indented how I expect it to be indented. I use [this syntax file](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1571) and [this indent file](http://www.2072productions.com/vim/indent/php.vim).

Comment: note - i'm not using cindent, is there anything else I need to have in my .vimrc file?

Comment: If you are editing via SSH, you can use SFTP to use a GUI editor. I use it with Kate all the time.

Comment: @John i know, but that's not exactly the solution I'm looking for.

Comment: Can anyone confirm and post .vimrc file if 2072productions indent file works for you on my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be because your closure syntax is incorrect. Closures shouldn't have names as far as I know. E.g. for a preg_replace_callback function, you'd either pass a variable containing a closure defined with `function($matches){/* logic */}` or the aforementioned code itself.

What you're trying to do here is define a function in a callback argument. BAAAAD for your script xD

Just get rid of the name like this and see if it helps:

```
myfunc(function(){
    echo "hello";
    if(1==2){
        echo "world";
    }
});
```

PHP docs show this syntax for closures too:
http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php

Comment: Whops sorry. I wasn't paying attention. I have fixed the closure but formatting is still incorrect.

Comment: I don't know then - I just thought that it could be failing because `vim` didn't properly understand what was happening due to the error with the closure.